# Highlight cells in one column based on date in adjacent column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I change the cell fill color of the cells in a certain column when it is 16 days past the dates in the adjacent column?

The cell should only change color if the cell does not have any text in it.

eg. Cell E1 should change to blue fill if today's date is 16 days past the date in cell D1 AND cell E1 is blank (there is no text entered in this cell).

In the image, cell E1 needs to be highlighted blue as there is no text in it and it is beyond 16 days past the date in cell D1.
[image: Example image]

Comment: Hi coderrr, welcome to SO. You'd be better off splitting your questions into different posts rather than chaining them here together, even though they're functionnally related. Also, it would be a good start to show what you already tried and what (unwanted) results you got.

Comment: Also make sure you read [ask], take the [tour], and review [mcve] =)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used =AND((TODAY()-(INDIRECT("RC[-1]",0))>16), ($E1="")) in the conditional formatting menu and then used the drag option. It works!

Answer (score 0):

1. How to change the cell fill color of the cells in a certain column when it is 16 days past the dates in the adjacent column. The cell should only change color if the cell does not have any text in it. eg. Cell E1 should change to Blue fill if today's date is 16 days past the date in cell D1.

> with this one, you can try to use =now() in one cell once done,  subtract that to your your cell e1, you can use conditional formatting tool on the top side of your menubar in excel. (home > Style) go to conditional formatting> highlight cell > more rule > use formula.

Comment: Thanks for the reply to my question! How about the 16 days part? How would that formula look since I am trying to apply the formula to the whole column with respect to the dates in the whole adjacent column?

Comment: Can you try to upload your sample excel file so that i can help you better?

Comment: Image is uploaded!

Comment: check my added answer below. just change  the column a1 to f1 or beside the cell marked as blue then follow my instruction below.

Answer (score 0):

here's the sample one.
on your cell a1 , add this formula =e1-(date(year(now()),month(now()),day(now()))
once done, use the  conditional formatting to hightlight the cell e1 when value of  a1 =>16 days. 
go to conditional formatting> highlight cell > greater than option, a new field will show, highlight the cell a1 then add > 16.
make sure that you are on cell e1 when doing the conditional formatting.

dont forget to tag this up if this helps you :)

Comment: How do we check if a cell is blank or whether there is text in it?

Comment: you can use if condition on it but on the conditional formatting, it doesnt matter if the cell is blank, as long as it meets the condition then it will highlight.